# Why casting bool on boolean type return always false

Tags: php, casting

I want just to know why if I typecast — using (bool) — boolean value of an expression — e.g `2 < 1` —   return always `false` even if expresion return `true` ?

An example will say more clear

```
<?php
$value = (bool) 2 > 1;
var_dump($value); // bool(false)

$value = (bool) 2 < 1;
var_dump($value); // bool(false)

var_dump((bool)true) // bool(true)

var_dump((bool)false) // bool(false)
```

Comment: The cast has higher priority than the comparison operator.

Comment: Can you please tell more about it ?

Comment: I.e. `(bool) 2 > 1` is `((bool) 2) > 1` is `true > 1` is `false`. Use `(bool)(2 > 1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem

The cast has higher priority than the comparison operator. So in this expression:

```
$value = (bool) 2 > 1;
```

The `(bool)` cast associates with the literal `2` *before* the `>` operator is applied. Thus, that expression is equivalent to this:

```
$value = ((bool) 2) > 1;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$value = true > 1;
```

Which semantically makes no sense, but PHP allows, and converts to an integer, in order to apply the `>` operator, effectively giving:

```
$value = 1 > 1;
```

Which returns `false`.

---

#### Solution

The solution is to add parentheses and cast the entire expression:

```
$value = (bool)(2 > 1);
```

Parentheses can be helpful even when not necessary, because they make your intent clear to a more casual reader, even one that might not have the operator priority table memorized.

Comment: "Which frankly makes no sense" - As in C, `true` is `1`, `false` is `0`. `true > 1` is thus `1 > 1`, therefore `false`. (Not disagreeing that it makes no sense, just explaining why the result is as it is.)

Comment: @Amadan Thanks. Yes, I meant it makes no semantic sense. Interestingly, languages like Rust are learning from these mistakes and forbidding automatic bool type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting `2` to a **boolean** because casting has higher priority than comparison,  which returns `true`. Your expression is then:

```
true > 1
```

Which is `false`.
Put your expression between parentheses or cast the result of the expression:

```
$value = (bool) (2 > 1); // true

// Or
$value = 2 > 1;
var_dump((bool)$value); // true
```